# WPF C#: Sort DataGrid columns in code-behind

Tags: sorting, datagrid, header

I want to sort DataGrid columns by headers in code-behind

I have tried with this code

```
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataGridTemplateColumn dgtc in DataGrid1.Columns)
    {
        dgtc.CanUserSort = true;
        dgtc.SortMemberPath = header_names[i];
        i++;
    }
```

But I got a "InvalidCastException" for 'DataGridTemplateColumn dgtc' in foreach loop. What can be the solution?

Comment: Are you sure `DataGrid1.Columns` is a list of `DataGridTemplateColumn` instances? I have no idea about WPF or C# but InvalidCastException may be pointing to this error.

Comment: Yes that's probably the error. I still do not know what the solution is to this problem.